# Error: Couldn't update to Windows 8.1 preview. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: installation, troubleshooting, windows-8.1-preview

Trying to upgrade my PC, the process goes forward but in some point, it revers back to Windows 8.0.

How can I troubleshoot the problem?

[image]

Comment: Beta test software being used as an upgrade... Will have issues that are solved when Windows 8.1 RTM is released. Being a guinea pig in a bio lab gets old after while.

Comment: Is the question really about the Preview? The real thing exists since quite some time. And how are you doing the update?

Comment: @harrymc The OP is about the preview,transcends that if preview or RTM, ive same problem with RTM one, same error code 0xC1900101 - 0x4000D.

Comment: @harrymc Look at the date when the question was posted.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this advice](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_install/error-0xc1900101-0x4000d/737a94d7-0e3b-4ff2-925f-764ffb3acae3) :

> 1. Remove any third-party antivirus
> 2. Enable windows firewall and defender
> 3. Launch the Run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), and enter "WSReset.exe" (reset Windows store)
> 4. Perform a clean Boot :
>
>    1. Launch the Run dialog again and enter `Msconfig.exe` (System Configuration)
>    2. Select the Services tab, check "Hide all Microsoft services" and click on the "Disable all" button. (Important: Do Not disable
>         Microsoft services)
>    3. Select the Startup tab and click on "Open Task Manager". In Task Manager under the Startup tab, disable all startup programs. Close
>         the task manager and System Configuration.
>    4. Restart PC.
> 5. After rebooting into Windows 8, reset the Windows store again (step 3) and run the Windows 8.1 Install from the Windows Store.
>
> After Windows 8.1 is installed, re-enable all the services disabled in
>   step 4b (except the two services I suspected maybe causing "Error
>   0xC1900101-0x4000D" : Facial Recognition and Bluetooth). In Task
>   Manager re-enable the startup programs.
>
> Further investigation has shown the Facial Recognition software
>   crashes my Windows 8.1 at boot.

Comment: the step one, seems to be the key.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling any third-party anti-virus/anti-malware app and ensuring no unnecessary programs/services are launched on startup and running in the background will help the Preview get installed smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

there's not yet official statement from Microsoft about this issue, but there are already a few cases. The best advise is to get rid of non Microsoft software especial the ones that have drivers installed. Also disable non Microsoft services and program from the startup, you can doing that by open the msconfig from de run.